# Splitting a list of dataframes into multiple lists based on a factor in each dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of data frames with a time series of (x, y) coordinates. Each data frame also has a specific variable - `trial_option` - which I want to use to split my list of data frames into multiple smaller lists. Each smaller list will contain all the data frames with one `trial_option` factor.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = runif(10, -10, 10), y = runif(10, -10, 10), trial_option = rep("A", 10))
df2 <- data.frame(x = runif(10, -10, 10), y = runif(10, -10, 10), trial_option = rep("A", 10))
df3 <- data.frame(x = runif(10, -10, 10), y = runif(10, -10, 10), trial_option = rep("B", 10))
df4 <- data.frame(x = runif(10, -10, 10), y = runif(10, -10, 10), trial_option = rep("B", 10))
df5 <- data.frame(x = runif(10, -10, 10), y = runif(10, -10, 10), trial_option = rep("C", 10))
df6 <- data.frame(x = runif(10, -10, 10), y = runif(10, -10, 10), trial_option = rep("C", 10))
mylist <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3, df4 = df4, df5 = df5, df6 = df6)
```

So I want to split `mylist` into 3 smaller lists: `mylistA, mylistB, mylistC`.
I thought I could use `small_list <- lapply(list, subset, trial_option == A)` and doing that for each trial_option but that did not return what I wanted. I also feel like repeating that for each trial_option would be tedious and not good practice. I haven't been able to find a suitable answer by googling yet.

Also, once I have these subset lists, I'll be doing some data wrangling and I then want to combine these smaller lists all back into a big list. Each subset of `trial_option` data frames needs to have separate data wrangling done, hence why I want to split the master list.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data frames can be combined into one and then splited on trial_optin

```
df <- rbind(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6)
split(x = df, f = df$trial_option)
```

Comment: I think this will do the trick, although I need to be able to split them back into their own individual data frames again. Would it work to add a variable to each dataframe giving it a unique ID and then using that ID to split it all back out again into separate data frames?

Comment: Yes, just make sure those are unique or use `unsplit()`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to perform processing on data frame splits, consider `by` the object-oriented wrapper of `tapply`. While similar to `split` in creating named list of subset dfs by one or more factors, `by` allows you to process each subset df further without any `lapply` or `for` loop afterwards.

```
mylist <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3, df4 = df4, df5 = df5, df6 = df6)

complete_df <- do.call(rbind, mylist)

# NAMED LIST OF DFS (NAMES ARE UNIQUE VALUES OF trial_option: A, B, C)
by_list <- by(complete_df, complete_df$trial_option, FUN=function(d) {    
    # DATA WRANGLING WHERE PARAMETER, d, IS SUBSETTED DATAFRAME
    d ...
    # RETURN A DATAFRAME AFTER PROCESSING
    return(new_d)
})

# ROW BIND ALL DF ELEMENTS (ASSUMES EACH HAVE SAME colnames() AND ncol())
new_complete_df <- do.call(rbind, by_list)
```